# How to call a method asynchronously in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, asynchronous, silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I'm developing a Silverlight app for SharePoint and want to get ListItems from a list. I know I need to query asynchronously to avoid blocking the UI thread. Normally I use ExecuteQueryAsync but that won't work since I like to set the result as DataGrid source.

How can I call the GetItemsFromList method asynchronously and set the result as DataGrid source without creating much code overhead? (lambda?)

SharePointHelper Class:

```
public static ListItemCollection GetItemsFromList(string name)
{
    var context = ClientContext.Current;
    var targetList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");

    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query>RowLimit>4</RowLimit></View>",
                                      name);

    ListItemCollection collListItems = targetList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    return collListItems;
}
```

UI Class:

```
private void SetDataGridItemSource()
{
    dataGrid.Source = GetItemsFromList("name");
}
```

I have now implemented the solution from Shawn Kendrot:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (sender, args) => 
{
    args.Result = SharePointHelpers.GetItemsFromList("name");
};
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => dataSource.Source = e.Result as ListItemCollection;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the ClientContext class for SharePoint (or even SharePoint for that matter), but I do not see any async methods in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext_members.aspx). If this call is going to be expensive, you can wrap the call in a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). The BackgroundWorker would execute the query and you can return the results. You would not be able to assign the Source as you have described, but instead would need to set the Source when the worker completes.

```
    private void SetDataGridItemSource()
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += WorkerOnDoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync("name");       
    }

    private void WorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.Argument != null)
        {
            string name = args.Argument.ToString();
            var context = ClientContext.Current;
            var targetList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query>RowLimit>4</RowLimit></View>",
                                              name);

            ListItemCollection collListItems = targetList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            args.Result = collListItems;
        }
    }

    private void WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        dataGrid.Source = args.Result as ListItemCollection;
    }
```

Comment: This would work but with this solution I need a BackgroundWorker for each methode I like to call and I have to register to the event. I have hoped for a niceer solution like @Dan Wray tried ;-)

Comment: Using a callback and subscribing to an event are essentially the same thing. As these methods do not appear to be async, you need to make them async. BackgroundWorker makes that possible. If you don't like having the completed method, just change the event subscription to: worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,e) => dataGrid.Source = e.Result as ListItemCollection;

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public delegate void ItemsLoadedCallback(IEnumerable<object> Entities);
public static void GetItemsFromList(string name, ItemsLoadedCallback Callback)
{
    // codesnip

    // Do async thing, on return call:
    if (Callback != null)
    {
        Callback(collListItems);
    }
}


private void SetDataGridItemSource()
{
    GetItemsFromList("name", (items) => dataGrid.Source = items);
}
```

Comment: Get this Error: The method or property that is called may block the UI thread and it is not allowed. Please use background thread to invoke the method or property, for example, using System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method to invoke the method or property.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sharepoint at all. I'm under the impression that you can make use of an "ExecuteQueryAsync" method somewhere to perform your query asynchronously, the code I've shown above only really shows how you can capture the result of this async call and return it to your original calling method via the delegate.  If you cannot perform the operation asynchronously natively you're likely stuck using a backgroundworker to do that, as shown in Shawn's solution.